# How to configure TCP connection timeout for node_redis js

Tags: sockets, tcp, redis, timeout, node-redis

Is there a way to configure tcp connection timeout when using **node_redis** (js redis client)? Or any other mature JS redis client?
On my prod enviroment I am getting very long TCP connection timeout (like 130 seconds) on connection retries when redis server is killed. So even if redis server starts responding in 5 seconds, my application is hanged for 130s + 3s (configured in retry_strategy). My retry_strategy:

```
            retry_strategy: (options) => {
            if (options.error) {
                RedisStore.log.debug(`${options.error.message}. Reconnecting in 3000`);
            }
            return 3000;
        }
```

My app log output to show the porblem:

```
2018-06-25T14:05:16.031Z debug Redis connection has been closed. ("end" event)
2018-06-25T14:05:19.037Z debug Reconnecting with Redis. ("reconnecting" event)
2018-06-25T14:07:28.102Z debug Redis connection to app-redis-master:6379 failed - connect ETIMEDOUT x.x.x.x:6379. Reconnecting in 3000ms. ("error" event - after 2min and 10s)
```

"end" event is emited immediately. The problem is that "error" event takes so long to be emited and retry_strategy is not fired again in that time. 
How can I configure the timeout to be shorter?